# Subscripts in R when adding other text

Tags: r, plotmath

How would you add a subscript to one particular word of a title in R? For example, suppose the title is `"A_2 and B_2."` How would you add these two subscripts? I know that `expression("A"[2])` and `expression("B"[2])` individually add subscripts to these letters.

Comment: Have you read `?plotmath`?

Answer (score 20):

You do not need `paste` (or quotes for that matter)  at all:

```
expression( A[2]~and~B[2] )
```

Test:

```
plot(1,1, main=expression( A[2]~and~B[2] ) )
```

The syntactic principle is that tildes (which creates a space)  and asterisks (non-space plotmath separator) are used to separate items and that no quotes are needed unless you are using a plotmath function name .... such as wanting the word "paste" or "sqrt" to appear in the displayed version of the expression.

Answer (score 7):

Just paste them together:

`expression(paste("A"[2], " and B"[2])`

Comment: `plot(x, main=expression(paste("A"[2], " and B"[2], sep="")))` (where x is your data...) doesn't work? What device + plot function are you using?

Comment: @Damien, this works using the method described as well as `> plot(x)`   `> title(expression(paste("A"[2], " and B"[2], sep="")))`   Please doublecheck your implementation

Comment: WILL PEOPLE PLEASE STOP USING `sep=` IN PLOTMATH `paste`? (It is not the same function as `base::paste`.)